# To some, to others, to what?

Tags: word-choice

What comes after "to others" here:

> To some, XYZ. To others, ABC. To ???, DEF

I am trying to say that is interpreted differently to three different groups and every word I substitute "???" for looks awkward or does not make sense.

What would make sense? Am I better off just rewriting this section?

Comment: @YosefBaskin not necessarily - to some I'm X, to others I'm Y, to everyone else I'm Z.

Comment: Try "to some . . . , to others . . . , and to *yet others . . ."*

Comment: Rewriting seems the best option; at least work out what the different groups are. Is the third option supposed to be a third group, or refer to everyone else? You could either name/describe the groups, or say something like "depending on X, they are known as A, B, or C" or if there is no reason for the difference "...can be known as A, B, or C."

Comment: to the rest, to the remainder, to yet more, to still more, to everyone else, to ... There are - as these possibilities and the comments show - many answers. Which you choose is a matter of taste, context and opinion. I would therefore suggest closing the question as a matter of opinion, but I refrain because you are a welcome newcomer to the site. Have a look at the site help/guidelines to see what constitutes a good question.

Comment: One the one hand, X; on the other hand, Y; on the third hand, Z